# Please help me with below test coverage

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have below  trigger. And i have one test class. Trigger is Covered 76%. i want to make it more than 90%.
The code which is not covered is at line numbers :  For Trigger 1 :14,17,25,26,27,32
For Trigger 2 :

Trigger 1:

```
   1 trigger updateAccount on Account (after update) {
    2 if(limitrecursion.runtwice()){
    3 System.debug('UpdateFirstCampaignOfContact RECURSIONLIMIT PASSED');
    4 List<Account> AccountList = new List<Account>();
    5 List<Account> updateAccountList = new List<Account>();
   6  Set<id> acctset = new Set<id>();
    7 Map<id,id> updateMap = new Map<id,id>();
     8 For(Account acc : Trigger.new){
     9 ID cid;
     10 if(acc.First_Contact__c==NULL){
     11 system.debug('***inside first contact  null');
     12 List<Contact> conList1 = [Select id from Contact Where accountid = : acc.id];
     13 if(conList1.size()>0){
     14 cid = [Select id from Contact Where accountid = : acc.id ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1].id ;
     15 }
     16 if(cid<>Null)
     17 updateMap.put(acc.id,cid);
     18 }
    19 else if(acc.First_Contact__c<>NULL){
    20 ID zid;
    21 system.debug('***inside first contact not null');
    22 List<Contact> conList = [Select id from Contact Where accountid = : acc.id];
    23 if(conList.size()==0){
    24 updateAccountList.add(new Account(id=acc.id,First_Contact__c=null));
    25 }else if(conList.size()>0){
    26 zid = [Select id from Contact Where accountid = : acc.id ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1].id ;
    27 updateAccountList.add(new Account(id=acc.id,First_Contact__c=zid));    
   28 }
    29}
    30 }
    31 For(id aid : updateMap.keyset()){
    32 updateAccountList.add(new Account(id=aid,First_Contact__c=updateMap.get(aid)));
    33 }
   34 system.debug('***update account list:'+updateAccountList);
   35 if(updateAccountList.size()>0){
   36 update updateAccountList;
   37 }
   38 }else
   39 {
   40 System.debug('UpdateFirstCampaignOfContact STOPPED BECAUSE OF REC LIMIT');
   41 }
   42 }
```

Trigger 2:

```
     trigger updateFirstContactField on Contact (after insert,after update) {
     Set<id> acctSet = new Set<id>();
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
     if(Trigger.IsInsert){
     List<Contact> conList = [Select id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE id in :    Trigger.newmap.keyset()];
    For(Contact c : conList){
    acctSet.add(c.AccountId);
    }
   List<Contact> Cons = new List<Contact>([select id, AccountId from Contact
         where accountid = : acctSet ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1]);
   For(Contact c : cons){
   if(c.AccountId <> NULL){
   accList.add(new Account(id=c.AccountId,First_Contact__c=c.id));
 }
 }
if(accList.size()>0)
update accList;
}
if(Trigger.IsUpdate){
 system.debug('***Inside Update***');
  Set<id> newacctSet = new Set<id>();
 For(Contact c : Trigger.NEW){
 acctSet.add(Trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).Accountid);
 }
  system.debug('***acctSet:'+acctSet);
  List<Contact> Cons = new List<Contact>([select id, AccountId from Contact
         where accountid = : acctSet ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1]);
 For(Contact c : cons){
 if(c.AccountId <> NULL){
  accList.add(new Account(id=c.AccountId,First_Contact__c=c.id));
 }
  }
  system.debug('***accList'+accList);
  List<Account> accList1 = [Select id,First_Contact__c from Account];
  For(Account acc : accList1){
 List<Contact> conList1 = [Select id from Contact Where accountid=:acc.id];
  if(conList1.size()==0 && acc.First_Contact__c<>Null)
{
//acc.First_Contact__c=null;
 accList.add(acc);
  }
  }
   if(accList.size()>0) 
  update accList;
 }
 }
```

Test Class :

```
    @isTest
        private class updateAccountTest {
        static testMethod void updateAccountTest() {
       Test.startTest();
       // Inserting a contact
       Contact objContactA1 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName1',lastName='lastName1');
       insert objContactA1;
       //create test data
       Account objAccountA = new Account(Name='testaccounta',First_Contact__c=objContactA1.id);
       insert objAccountA;
       objContactA1.accountid=objAccountA.id;
       update objContactA1;
       Account objAccountB = [Select id,First_Contact__c FROM Account where id = : objAccountA.id];
       objAccountB.First_Contact__c=null;
       update objAccountB;
       }

       static testMethod void updateAccountTest1() {
       Test.startTest();
       Account objAccountA = new Account(Name='testaccounta');
       insert objAccountA;
       // Inserting a contact
       Contact objContactA1 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName1',lastName='lastName1',accountid=objAccountA.id);
       insert objContactA1;
       //create test data
       Account objAccountB = [Select id,First_Contact__c FROM Account where id = : objAccountA.id];
       objAccountB.First_Contact__c=null;
       update objAccountB;
       Test.stopTest();
       }
}
```

Comment: better if you can point what are the uncovered lines. Check for if else blocks. Use some assertsequals in your test class.

Comment: @highfive i have updated my question now.

Comment: Looks like it should cover 14,17,etc. Do you have any validation rules or workflows related to `First_Contact__c` of the `Account` and `Contact`? Does it pass this test class?

Comment: Yes test class is passed. No issue with test class.There are no validation rules or workflows. But have one trigger on contact. Will update that trigger code in my question

Comment: Update my question with other trigger

Comment: Please don't dump entire code classes, but ask yourself why you are not able to cover these lines of code. Having asked yourself that question, you will either be able to cover them, or know why you are not able to and thereby know on what to ask our help.  Any questions that are not specific may be closed as "too  broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of - limitrecursion.runtwice(). Also, I now see that the contact updated the account. You will need to reset the value of limitrecursion.runtwice() as another update to the account will not get past that part

I would change the test class to be

```
   static testMethod void updateAccountTest() {
       Test.startTest();
       //create test data
       Account objAccountA = new Account(Name='testaccounta');
       insert objAccountA;

       // Inserting a contact
       Contact objContactA1 = new Contact(AccountID = objAccountA.id,FirstName='firstName1',lastName='lastName1');
       insert objContactA1;

       objAccountA.First_Contact__c = null;
       //**Reset the recursion flag so line 2 passes** 
      update objAccountA;
    }
```

When you update the account is it preventing

There are other issue with your code though. As an example, why are you doing this:

```
List<Contact> conList1 = [Select id from Contact Where accountid = : acc.id];
      if(conList1.size()>0){
      cid = [Select id from Contact Where accountid = : acc.id ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1].id ;
      }
      if(cid<>Null)
      updateMap.put(acc.id,cid);
      }
```

When you should be doing this:

```
List<Contact> conList1 = [Select id from Contact Where accountid = : acc.id ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1];
      if(conList1.size()>0){
         cid =conList1[0].id ;
         updateMap.put(acc.id,cid);

      }
```

Comment: Ok i will make changes as per your code. But when i updated account still its not showing any changes in code coverage. Can you modify test class and post it in answer.

Comment: I did same in test class as per your code. But it did nt increase anything.

Comment: See updated code.

Comment: Updated again please recheck. I believe the recursion check was causing it to not run as the contact trigger updated the account, so when you attempted to set the First_Contact__c to null the check at line 2 was stopping the trigger

Comment: Checking the code in system. Will update you. Thanks for helping.